# Xamarin Forms Local Notification

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, notifications, localnotification

i am new to xamarin form and i want to make local notification for cross platform. I use a plugin call Local Notifications Plugin for Xamarin by edsnider ( Link - https://github.com/edsnider/LocalNotificationsPlugin ) and follow as what the documentation ask me to do.

I create a button and use this code as it's function. The idea is to get a notification when the button is clicked

```
void Notify()
    {
        CrossLocalNotifications.Current.Show("Alert", "People spot", 10);
    }
```

and i get this error when i press on the button in my android device.

> System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not
>   implemented.

Hope to solve this matter soon. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin Plugins implement functionality that is usually platform specific. Because of that you have to **install the plugin in all your projects** - all platform projects and your PCL. The error you are gettng seems that the plugin is not properly installed in one of the projects.

If you have installed it into all your projects, please try to uninstall it from all projects, clean your solution and install from NuGet again.

Also note that notifications on macOS are not yet supported.

Answer (score 0):

In the [source codes](https://github.com/edsnider/LocalNotificationsPlugin/blob/master/src/Plugin.LocalNotifications/CrossLocalNotifications.cs), here:

```
        private static ILocalNotifications CreateLocalNotificationsImplementation()
        {
#if NETSTANDARD1_0
            return null;
#else
            return new LocalNotificationsImplementation();
#endif
        }
```

If your [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/libraries#prerequisites) is 1.0, it will return `null`, and then `Current` will `throw NotImplementedInReferenceAssembly();`, so you get `NotImplementedException`.

Please check your the version of .Net Framework in your PCl's Properties file.

If it is 1.0, you need change it.

If it is not 1.0, the exception means that there is no `LocalNotificationsImplementation` instance on your Android platform, do like @Martin Zikmund has suggested.